# How to set new JIRA administrator password without any db coding?

Tags: hash, passwords, jira, administration

User Administrator takes his password from "JIRA Internal Directory" (which means from database, as I understand). I know this password, but in some reasons I want to reset it. But in Administrator's profile there is no link "Set password".

All I found on the Internet - how to send password by e-mail (not to change it!) and view/change it's hash right in database by SQL query.

Is there any method that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to Admin, System, General Config and change External User Management to off. Then put the internal directory at the top in the list of User Directories. Go to the admin's profile and click on Change Password. Then undo the previous steps